# Userless Oauth (Facebook)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am trying to build a backend rails app that goes to a public facebook page, and pulls down any new posts.. But of course, i am running into issues with authentication.

I am able to do everything that i want, when using the sample access token provided [here](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer).

```
HTTParty.get("https://graph.facebook.com/#{name}/posts?access_token=#######################################")
```

But apparently this access token expires. I dont have any front-end component to this app, as it is not intended to be managed, or accessed by a user. All i need is basic permissions, because i am only interested in public pages.

I am happy to hard code my log-in info, if this authentication step could be automated.

Does anyone know how i can obtain a basic oauth access token without needing a user to click the "approve" button?

Comment: Why have all of my posts been getting down voted lately? I feel like I provide sufficient explanation of my issue, do I not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try the Client Credentials OAuth flow:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/

This allows you to pass in your application's `client_id` and `client_secret` to obtain an access token.  Make a request like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
    client_id=YOUR_APP_ID
   &client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET
   &grant_type=client_credentials
```

The `access_token` is returned in the response. You can then use this access token to make requests as your app instead of making them on behalf of any individual user.

I'm not positive this has the ability to retrieve public pages as you intend, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: An app access token can be used to query a page's details provided there aren't any demographic restrictions in place on the page (so, you're correct)